# Algorithm for matching similar content text items

Tags: algorithms

I am working on a website (C#, ASP.Net MVC 3) which reads some RSS feeds from multiple sources and put feed title and summary in a database table(Sql Server).

What I want to do is:
Put an algorithm in place which can relate multiple feeds. For example if each feed is a news item, I would like to relate all news which says in different grammar of English "Some has won some election".

Is there any standard algorithm for such kind of content matching logic? 
If not, what kind of custom algorithm should be used?

If this logic can be written on Database side(e.g. Stored Procedure) it will be better.

Comment: Read the [Wikipedia article on Natural Language Processing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing), especially the "The future of NLP" chapter. What you're asking doesn't (yet) have a 100% solution, so you should start looking at compromises.

Answer (score 3):

As @Cosmin-Prund said, there's no trivial or good pre-existing way to do this.  My off-the-top-of-my-head suggestion would be to use a search engine like [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/) to tokenize and store the feed title.  Use a [stemming tokenizer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3875382/298754), so that you can match words even if they're in different forms (such as `wins` vs `winning`).  Then, when you process a new feed, you can search for the title as keywords, and see what you get back.  You'll have to play with it some to find out how to tune the results to do what you want (try dropping the two most common tokens?), but it ought to be in the right ballpark of what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I've actually been looking into doing something similar.  As a good starting point, I found an open source project called [mahout](http://mahout.apache.org/) which implements most of the algorithms you need, although it is far from a plug and play solution.

The three use cases you might be interested in are clustering, recommendation, and classification.  They all basically group items into related topics, but in subtly different ways.

- Use **recommendation** when you have a bunch of news articles and are trying to determine which ones you are most likely to like based on your past reading habits and those of readers similar to you.
- Use **classification** when you want to group the news articles into subjects, and you know beforehand what those subjects should be.  This is most useful for long term, ongoing topics, like the weather, for example.
- Use **clustering** when you want to group the news articles into basic subjects, and you don't know beforehand what those subjects should be.  This is most useful for one-time events, like the death of Hugo Chavez, for example.

If you're looking for a more complete solution, check out [Carrot2](http://project.carrot2.org/).  It is only able to handle around 1,000 documents, though.  Perhaps useful if you are only interested in clustering one day's worth of news from a few select rss feeds.

Answer (score 1):

I've used an approach based on [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) to find similar phrases and words. It doesn't understand semantics, but it's used to find a concrete number telling "how similar are these two phrases". The algorithm itself are quick and easy and I know it's implemented in a few databases as well.

Comment: It's a good idea in theory, but the problem with it is that a single-word change can make a huge difference. Consider: `Hurricane Strikes New Orleans, causes mass devastation` vs `Hurricane Strikes New Jersey, causes mass devastation`.  One is a news story from 2005, the other is from 2012.

Answer (score 0):

On the Database side, the Postgresql database engine, since version 8.3, has the feature: [Fuzzy String Match](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/fuzzystrmatch.html)

It "provides several functions to determine similarities and distance between strings."

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can take a minhash based near duplication detection approach since the text is relatively long (considering the content). There's a good article [here](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/near-duplicates-and-shingling-1.html)